# How to have the background-size same as image size during hovering over the image using CSS?

Tags: html, css

When I hover over the image, then the background changes to yellow. The image is circular but the background remains rectangular. How to have the background-size same as image size during hovering over the image using CSS?

```css
body {
  background-color: #393b44;
  color: #8d93ab;
  font-family: helvetica;
}

hr {
  border-color: #8d93ab;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: dotted none none;
  width: 5%;
}

h1 {
  color: #8d93ab;
}

h3 {
  color: #8d93ab;
}

a:link {
  color: #d6e0f0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: yellow;
}

img:hover {
  background-color: #393b44;
  transform: scale(.85);
}
```

Comment: could you please add your code here , to be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

You should add your code with the question,

This might be useful:

```
wrap the img inside a div
<div><img src="" ></div>
```

and add styles to the `div`

```
div {

  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  display:block;
  background-color:yellow;

}
```

Comment: and html needed for knowing the structure

Comment: A short explanation to your code snippets would help improve this answer.